# What is Stack Exchange's resiliency/availability story?

Tags: discussion, outage

How resilient is Stack Exchange to outages?  Is there an automatic failover process?

The Stack Exchange websites were down for maintenance for two hours yesterday ([5pm to 7pm PST on a Saturday](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/12/05/database-server-upgrade-outage-today)).

Here's the only info I have at the moment:

- That blog post (above) mentions they have a backup database server.
- The [Stack Overflow podcasts](https://stackoverflow.blog/podcast) imply they only use one main web server, with no load balancing - which surprised me a bit.

Comment: They allocated 2 hours, but it was really only about 45 minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use [load balancing](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/load-balancing-stack-overflow/). And I think for a Q&A site the resilience is good enough.

Comment: Podcast #68 goes into more detail about this:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/podcast-68/  Typical that it was the next one on my playlist!

Answer (score 8):

I personally don't have a problem with maintenance outages of **a few hours every 4-6 months**.

I just don't see the Trilogy as a mission critical service where we *cannot* have downtime.

Comment: Yes, it seems reasonable.  I was surprised at the choice of time for the maintenance window, but I see you've explained it was a typical low point in weekly traffic in a comment here:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/database-server-upgrade-outage-today/#comment-41685