# IIS configuration (memory and process) on the StackExchange servers

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, server

In regards to the IIS configuration of the Stack Exchange servers, is IIS running as a 32 bit or 64 bit process?

I'm assuming the web servers are running 64bit Server 2008.

Since Stack Overflow is so performant, I'm just wondering if the SE team could share some of the settings like max/min memory, recycle strategy, threadcounts,  etc.

Of course if this is asked somewhere else (I couldn't find it here or on blog.stackoverflow.com) please just provide a link... I'm sure this info must already be out there since the SE team is pretty good at communicating their juicy awesomeness.

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70169/how-does-stack-overflow-scale http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32045/what-is-stackoverflows-resiliency-availability-story http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't generally change any of these settings. So it's simply out of box Server 2008 R2 IIS 7.5